# Jwplayer Caching issue

Tags: javascript, caching, jwplayer

> How does jwplayer cache work in browsers ?

Previously, I had been using flash player for playing our videos, recently I started using jwplayer.

I am showing a video in popup on clicking on a thumbnail of the video and at first time it loads, second time also it loads and plays the video.after user has played the video, user closes the video and *"popup is removed "*, I am not hiding the pop up but removing and loading the second video in the same popup.
My Expectation was that loading time of video should be less, it should be faster as compared to first time load but it is not so.

whereas in flash player caching works, and second time loading of video takes less time.

What can I do to use caching in jwplayer? I am using Drupal7 and jwplayer for my videos.

Comment: Can I see a link to where you are running this?

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer : Thanks for the reply!!! I have this in drupal site , let me create a jsfiddle separately for this and I will share the demo page.

Comment: instead of removing the player I am using new setup to show/hide the player and it works better

Comment: Ok, great, glad that worked for you.